# DELETE EM SQL COM INSTRUÇÃO WHERE SEM NECESSIDADE DE ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, delete, pentaho

Tenho tabela de CEPs com um novo campo OPERACAO com informações de DEL para deletar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando realizo a instrução:

```
DELETE FROM cepdb.log_bairro where BAI_OPERACAO = 'del';
```

Retorna:

```
2 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cepdb`.`log_faixa_bairro`, CONSTRAINT `LOG_FAIXA_BAIRRO_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`BAI_NU`) REFERENCES `log_bairro` (`BAI_NU`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT) SQL2.sql 1 1
```

Como deletar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está informando que existe um **ligação com chave estrangeira com uma chave primaria** de uma tabela chamada **LOG_FAIXA_BAIRRO**.

Para resolver esse problema é necessário excluir as informações que contenham o mesmo **BAI_NU** (que é uma chave **primaria**) da tabela **LOG_FAIXA_BAIRRO** para que quando seja realizada a exclusão na tabela **LOG_BAIRRO** não ocorra esse tipo de erro.

Resumindo, exclua primeiro os **BAI_NU** da tabela de **LOG_FAIXA_BAIRRO**, para depois excluir da tabela **LOG_BAIRRO**, você pode solucionar esse problema executando os seguintes comandos:

```
--PRIMEIRO COMANDO (UTILIZEI O SUBSELECT)
DELETE FROM cepdb.log_faixa_bairro fb 
WHERE fb.BAI_NU IN (SELECT lb.BAI_NU 
                    FROM cepdb.log_bairro lb 
                    WHERE lb.BAI_OPERACAO = 'del');

--SEGUNDO SEGUNDO
DELETE FROM cepdb.log_bairro WHERE BAI_OPERACAO = 'del';
```